# How to have multi level theads in table of html and place data in the shown image fashion?

Tags: html

Here as you can see I have 4 headings in the beginning, and then **chemical composition** have number of sub-headings. I want to place the data in that order.

What I have tried doing is this-

```
<table class="editable-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="editable-table-header">Field</th>
          <th class="editable-table-header">Field1</th>
          <th class="editable-table-header">Field2</th>
          <th class="editable-table-header">Field3</th>
          <th class="editable-table-header">
            Value
            <colgroup>
              <col span="5" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
              <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
            </tr>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
          <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
          <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
          <td class="editable-table-data">fieldval</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Should I just have two tables side by side? It sure doesnt feel the right way. Apologies its a very basic question. but I have never really interacted with tables much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could achieve your example using the `colspan` and `rowspan` properties.

Here is some good documentation:
[td rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I shall have a look on it